# building Qt 5.4 errors in Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

When I built Qt 5.4 in mac, I got quite many errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libQt5Bootstrap.a(qstring_mac.o)
  "_FSFindFolder", referenced from:
      macLocation(QStandardPaths::StandardLocation, short) in libQt5Bootstrap.a(qstandardpaths_mac.o)
```

......
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
make[2]: make[2]: *** [../../../bin/rcc] Error 1*** [../../../bin/moc] Error 1

make[1]: *** [sub-rcc-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [sub-moc-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Any idea what causes these errors?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Let's see your QMake file.

Comment: Do you mean the MakeFile?

Comment: you read me correctly: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmake-project-files.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with new version Qt 5.4.1 build on Mac OS 10.9

Mac-Build-DSBrowser:qt-src-static-5.4.1 jenkins$ ./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -release -static -accessibility -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -no-cups -no-sql-sqlite -no-qml-debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtserialport -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtxmlpatterns

And then used make -j4